# I want a bot to send random messages only but one message only once

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

It Is Something Like This

I have these 5 messages

hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
hello5

And I want to send a random message

like hello3

But It Could Be Sent Only Once

Its Shortly Bot Sends Random Messages. But Messages Could Not Be Repeated

I want to do this in discord.js v14

Comment: This Is Huge Project Bro

Comment: So Please Help Bro

Comment: What should happen after all 5 messages have been sent? Does the bot just stop responding?

Comment: um sending message saying no message

Comment: Here's an example of stateful random iteration of an input array: https://tsplay.dev/mqkXqw

Answer (score 1):

Your post is kinda confusing, but if you wanted to send a random message, use an array.

```js
let randomStrings = ["message1", "message2", "message3", "message4", "message5"];
let randomLength = randomStrings.length;
let RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomLength);
let sendRandomString = randomStrings[RN]
```

Here's the snippet:

```js
let randomStrings = ["message1", "message2", "message3", "message4", "message5"];
let randomLength = randomStrings.length;
let RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomLength);
let sendRandomString = randomStrings[RN]
console.log(sendRandomString)
```

Since you don't provide any code of yours. This is only the code I can give as tips.